# My web browser only works with https links?

Tags: vb.net, http, browser, https

I am making a simple web browser using Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition and Visual Basic. I have added the code below. My browser works, however my problem is that it only seems to work with HTTPS protocol links. I think this is because http automatically throws an error which causes my error handler to run, which retries the website with a https prefix. However I do not know what that error might be or how to fix it... Can you help?

CODE:

```
Public Class Form1
    'One button for go. Other for settings -incognito, history, homepage????
```

`'Window button actions

Private Sub Green_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Green.Click
    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
End Sub

Private Sub Yellow_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Yellow.Click
    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
End Sub

Private Sub Red_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Red.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    TitleText.Parent = Grey
    TitleText.BackColor = Color.Transparent

    TitleTextDivider.Parent = Grey
    TitleTextDivider.BackColor = Color.Transparent

    VersionText.Parent = Grey
    VersionText.BackColor = Color.Transparent
End Sub

Public Sub GoButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GoButton.Click
    'Add checking blacklist and adding link to history file here later. Use separate subs and call them here for better organisation.

    Dim Input As String = TextBox1.Text
    'Prefix with http and www
    Input = "http://www." + Input
    'Convert to Uri
    Dim Url As Uri = New Uri(Input)
    'Set as url
    WebBrowser1.Url = Url
    'Refresh
    WebBrowser1.Refresh()
    'On error, retry with https
    On Error GoTo HTTPS_Handler
HTTPS_Handler:
    'New String URL, replacing http with https
    Dim HTTPS_Input As String = Replace(Input, "http", "https")
    'All we did last time, again...
    Dim NewUrl As Uri = New Uri(HTTPS_Input)
    WebBrowser1.Url = NewUrl
    WebBrowser1.Refresh()
End Sub
End Class`

Don't worry about the first bit, just focus on the bit after "Public sub GoButton_clicked"...

Comment: Should work, but probably not handling the fact that some sites try to auto redirect to HTTPS (Google is an example of this). Read up on proper error handling using Try/Catch and tell us what error you are getting. http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vb.net/4232/error-handling/14828/try-catch-finally-statement#t=201608011838059034895

Comment: Is there any way to do this without doing a try/catch? Can I somehow test if a website is trying to redirect me?

Comment: That's not what I was saying. Use a try/catch so you can capture what error it is actually throwing, then you have something to search on to try and fix the issue. Right now, it is blowing up and you are throwing the exception away, but have no clue what the exception was.

Answer (score 0):

Your trying to use the old VB6 style of error handling. As the comments above suggested it would be better in VB.Net to use newer Try\Catch syntax.

If you want to keep it write it like so...

```
Public Sub GoButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GoButton.Click
    On Error GoTo HTTPS_Handler

    Dim Input As String = TextBox1.Text
    Input = "http://www." + Input

    Dim Url As Uri = New Uri(Input)
    WebBrowser1.Url = Url
    WebBrowser1.Refresh()

    Exit Sub

HTTPS_Handle:
    Dim HTTPS_Input As String = Replace(Input, "http", "https")
    Dim NewUrl As Uri = New Uri(HTTPS_Input)
    WebBrowser1.Url = NewUrl
    WebBrowser1.Refresh()
End Sub
```

Note the 'Exit Sub' to keep it from going into the error handling code if there isn't an error. Which it would be doing as it currently stands so you may not have an error at all but just unintentionally refreshing the page reguardless.

Plus there is an error variable you can check in the error handling see Err.Description and Err.Number